# IIS, Url Rewrite and ARR concurrent requests limits

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module, arr

In IIS we had a Website with 3 applications, each configured with its own AppPool.
After a refactoring process we decided to unify these application into one.
In order to let not updated clients to continue to communicate with the old URLs I decided to configure Url Rewrite and Application Request Routing (ARR) and to use the ARR proxy to accept requests on old URLs and remake them into the new ones.

On Monday (this is the first Monday after we set up the new configuration, and the past days everything worked fine) at 8am we have the clients that start a procedure to send some data to the server (on one of the old applications).
We have more than 1000 clients and the procedure makes about 10 calls to the API.
(The requests are normally resolved in less than 10ms.)
So we have this burst of more than 10000 calls (plus the ordinary ones) in 1-2 minutes.

With the old configuration with the 3 separate applications and no proxy we seldom had some issues, but this morning we had a system outage.

In the IIS logs I see that from 7:59:00 to 7:59:59 the server handled around 7000 requests (about half are the original ones from the clients and the other the ones made by the proxy) with no problems, but shortly after that I see only the original requests, all ended in timeout after more than 120s and a status of 502.3 64.
That change was sudden, so from 1-10 ms to 120000ms+ in 2 requests, so it is quite obvious that a limit was hit.

I am no such a server expert and I searched if there are some limits on the ARR proxy, but I didn't find many useful info.
I suspect, however, that the issue is not at all in the proxy, but in the AppPools configuration.

The current configuration is:

- 1 Website with the 3 applications (let's call it N: the new one and O1 and O2 the old ones),
- the directories of the O1 and O2 applications contains only the web.config file with the URL Rewrite rules,
- 3 Application Pools (NAP, O1AP, O2AP), so each application still have its own application pool,
- the configuration of the 3 AppPools is pretty much the standard one (so a queue length of 1000) with no managed code and integrated pipeline,
- the timeouts are 120s either on the ARR side and the IIS side.

The thing I don't know is what exactly happen when an old URL is hit and which AppPools are involved.
From what I understood, the request made to O1 lives in O1AP, then the proxy makes it own request to N and that request lives in NAP, so there should be no much difference between this configuration and the old one with the 3 separate applications.

The culprit I think is the 1000 requests queue length, but the issue I having with this is that on the advanced settings of the AppPool, when selecting the "Queue length" row, on the bottom pane the description says that when the queue is full the new requests are failed with HTTP503, but in the IIS logs I see 502.3.

Hoping the situation is clear enough, my questions are:

- is there something I am missing?
- which are the options to monitor the situation?
- what can I do to solve the issue?

Some versions:

- Windows server 2019
- IIS 10.0.17763.1,
- IIS URL Rewrite Module 2 7.2.1993
- ARR 3.0 3.0.05311

Comment: `502.3 64` says to me the backend app crashed or failed to respond before a timeout. Have you checked the HTTPERR logs (%windir%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR)? Have you checked the system and application Event Logs (Exceptions/app pool restarts etc)? Whats the longest time the backend took to respond when busy before the change (was it ever more than 120 seconds)? Do you care how long the requests take to ARR when busy? Do you have any logging/telemetry for the backend app? Is your server physical/virtual/cloud?

Comment: "After a refactoring process we decided to unify these application into one." is a rather pointless move. Why? Have you performed load testing ever before this Monday to ensure the unified web app can handle heavy load? Keep in mind web apps should be of small memory footprints and respond fast, so merging many to a single one clearly violates that basic rule. Has little to do with ARR rules as it can handle much higher load itself. Roll back all your changes and ask the developers to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, it is difficult to determine the cause of the problem. You can use a Windows performance monitoring tool to track your server's resource usage, such as CPU, memory, and disk usage, during traffic spikes.

Comment: @MisterSmith thank you for your comment. In the HTTPERR file I see the failed requests made by the proxy with reason "Connection_Dropped_List_Full". In the application log I do not see any errors (probably because the requests did not reach the application) and also in the system logs I do not see anything related to the issue. Before the issue, all the issue-related requests (so the original and the proxyed) took from some ms to 50-60ms at max. In the application I use Serilog in Debug level but no telemetry. The server is a single VMWare virtual machine (4cpu 8GB ram).

Comment: @LexLi I'm working on this project alone (Desktop/Android clients, server apps and management, db management etc, with many different languages and technologies to learn) so it is almost impossible to be expert on everything also because I'm working also on other projects... The choice under the unification was that the server app should have been unique from the start as all is related to the same thing, but for many reasons (time, little experience and so on) we split it in multiple apps. The issue is that the info were spread on 3 different websites/databases so a unification was needed.

Comment: @MisterSmith I wrote an incorrect thing in the previous comment, because in the application log I do see some errors, but they are very few in relation of the number of requests and they started to appear after more than a minute after the begin of the issue. The error is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: The client has disconnected
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800704CD): È stata tentata un'operazione su una connessione di rete inesistente. (0x800704CD)"

Comment: For us, it is impossible to reproduce your problem, the best way is to use failed request tracking, it will provide the key error and warning, which will help you to identify the problem.
This link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error:
https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis.

Comment: @YurongDai Thank you for the answers. I'll try to monitor the requests using the suggested method. In order to solve the issue quickly I updated the clients and now the data are sent at a random minute, so there is no burst anymore. So at least for now the issue is solved (I hope), but the questionis still relevant because I'm also interestend in understanding what happened and why. At the moment we have only a production-server but in the future they'll move the vm to Azure so if the old server remain active I'll set up some stress tests to better investigate the issue.